# Impossible to debug error while packaging Electron React app after adding Redux but works perfectly in developement

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, electron

So I forked this [repo](https://github.com/alexdevero/electron-react-webpack-boilerplate) to use in my project. It does not come with Redux, so I thought I could integrate Redux into it and use it, so I though about recreating the classic Counter app.

Interestingly, the app works perfectly fine in development. But whenever I am trying to package the application, it is spitting out errors that is impossible to debug.

```
$ npm run package

> electron-react-webpack-boilerplate@1.11.0 package C:\Users\Phantomhive\Documents\Code\Node.js\electron-react-redux-webpack-boilerplate
> npm run build


> electron-react-webpack-boilerplate@1.11.0 build C:\Users\Phantomhive\Documents\Code\Node.js\electron-react-redux-webpack-boilerplate
> cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.build.config.js --mode production

(node:5892) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new API on `.hooks` instead
Hash: e6d8267a937c49e70318
Version: webpack 4.43.0
Time: 3351ms
Built at: 05/14/2020 4:39:27 PM
 2 assets
Entrypoint main = bundle.css main.js

ERROR in unknown: Unexpected token (729:15)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! electron-react-webpack-boilerplate@1.11.0 build: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.build.config.js --mode production`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the electron-react-webpack-boilerplate@1.11.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Phantomhive\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-14T10_39_27_934Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! electron-react-webpack-boilerplate@1.11.0 package: `npm run build`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the electron-react-webpack-boilerplate@1.11.0 package script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Phantomhive\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-14T10_39_27_960Z-debug.log
```

**2020-05-14T10_39_27_960Z-debug.log**

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'package' ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v10.16.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'prepackage', 'package', 'postpackage' ]
5 info lifecycle electron-react-webpack-boilerplate@1.11.0~prepackage: electron-react-webpack-boilerplate@1.11.0
6 info lifecycle electron-react-webpack-boilerplate@1.11.0~package: electron-react-webpack-boilerplate@1.11.0
7 verbose lifecycle electron-react-webpack-boilerplate@1.11.0~package: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle electron-react-webpack-boilerplate@1.11.0~package: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Phantomhive\Documents\Code\Node.js\electron-react-redux-webpack-boilerplate\node_modules\.bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\condabin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn;C:\Users\Phantomhive\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64;C:\xampp\php;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018b\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018b\bin;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\mpv.install\tools;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git LFS;C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin;C:\Users\Phantomhive\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\Hostx64\x64;C:\Users\Phantomhive\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Phantomhive\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64;C:\Users\Phantomhive\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.1\bin;.;C:\chromedriver_win32;C:\ffmpeg\bin;C:\Program Files\heroku\bin;C:\Users\Phantomhive\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin
9 verbose lifecycle electron-react-webpack-boilerplate@1.11.0~package: CWD: C:\Users\Phantomhive\Documents\Code\Node.js\electron-react-redux-webpack-boilerplate
10 silly lifecycle electron-react-webpack-boilerplate@1.11.0~package: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'npm run build' ]
11 silly lifecycle electron-react-webpack-boilerplate@1.11.0~package: Returned: code: 2  signal: null
12 info lifecycle electron-react-webpack-boilerplate@1.11.0~package: Failed to exec package script
13 verbose stack Error: electron-react-webpack-boilerplate@1.11.0 package: `npm run build`
13 verbose stack Exit status 2
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
14 verbose pkgid electron-react-webpack-boilerplate@1.11.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\Phantomhive\Documents\Code\Node.js\electron-react-redux-webpack-boilerplate
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17763
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "package"
18 verbose node v10.16.3
19 verbose npm  v6.9.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 2
22 error electron-react-webpack-boilerplate@1.11.0 package: `npm run build`
22 error Exit status 2
23 error Failed at the electron-react-webpack-boilerplate@1.11.0 package script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 2, true ]
```

Link to my repo with the changes I have done is [here](https://github.com/mahieyin-rahmun/electron-react-webpack-boilerplate/commits/master), adding all the code here would have been cumbersome to read.

Thanks in advance for any guidelines.

**EDIT**

If I take out Redux stuff, e.g. not include the Counter component in App.js and comment out everything related to the Redux store setup in index.js, the app packages without errors. Sorcery!

Comment: Cloned the repo on a mac and it worked, no errors. `npm run build` and then `/builds/electron-react-webpack-boilerplate-darwin-x64/electron-react-webpack-boilerplate.app/Contents/MacOS/electron-react-webpack-boilerplate` started the electron app

Comment: I will give it a go on my Linux machine, then.

Comment: No luck. Same issue. `npm run build` fails with the same error on Linux. `ERROR in unknown: Unexpected token (2985:15)`

Comment: The only thing I did different is that I ran `yarn install` and `yarn start` then `yarn build`. I noticed you are using npm so ran `npm run build` and it worked. Maybe npm did not install correctly?

Comment: same issue with `yarn` as well. Just to clarify, by "repo" did you mean the original one, or the one with my changes, e.g. Redux store and stuff?

Comment: I did `git clone https://github.com/mahieyin-rahmun/electron-react-webpack-boilerplate.git`

Comment: Wow. How am I supposed to debug this now lol. I don't think it's an issue with npm or yarn because `npm run start` or `yarn start` works perfectly fine. Thanks a lot for your efforts, though.

Comment: A `git log` gives me `Fix issues link` as last commit. You can try with this commit, remove `package-lock.json`, `yarn.lock` and node_modules then do a `yarn install`. Another way to do it is to check out the repo in a clean directory and do `yarn install` and `yarn build`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. This was a ride.

#### TL;DR: Install "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread" if you are going to use the spread operator, e.g. `{ ... state, rest }`

#### Details:

After studying webpack and babel in general, I had a few ideas. One of them was to disable production mode in the build script.

`cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --mode production --config webpack.build.config.js`

became

`cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.build.config.js`

This basically stopped the bundled js files from being minified/uglified, so I could take a look at it.

Note: This usually spits out errors from webpack that no mode was set in the config files, so I added `mode: "none"` in the config files as well.

Then taking a look at the bundled js, I saw the error was in the following line from my reducer:

```
// counterReducer.js
return 
{
--> ...state,
    count: state.count + 1
}
```

The problem was babel being unable to understand what the heck this was. So, I looked this issue up, and came across [@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread). I installed the plugin using `npm i --save @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread` and included it in **.babelrc** file.

```
// .babelrc file
{
  ...
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"]
}
```

And it began to work perfectly fine in both development and production mode.

Perhaps all of the above could be avoided if I had simply used the core JS API, e.g.

```
Object.assign({}, state, { count: state.count + 1 })
```

but I haven't tested it.